# How to return the std::unique_ptr containing custom deleter in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr, return-type

My application compiler could only support up to `c++11`.

Below is a snip code of my project and function `get_conn()` returns `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter (deleter needs two arguments). I'm using `auto` keyword for return type but it gives an error like if is compiled with `c++11` (compiles fine with `c++14`)

```
error: ‘get_conn’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type
```

Sample code for demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


// Dummy definition of API calls                                                                                                             
int* open_conn (int handle)
{
  return new int;
}
void close_conn (int handle, int *conn)
{}

auto get_conn (int handle)
{
  // API call                                                                                                                                
  int* conn = open_conn (handle);    
  auto delete_conn = [](int *conn, int handle) {
        // API call                                                                                                                          
    close_conn (handle, conn);
    delete conn;
  };
  auto delete_binded = std::bind (delete_conn, std::placeholders::_1, handle);
  return std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(delete_binded)> (conn, delete_binded);
}

int main()
{
  int handle = 2; // suppose                                                                                                                 
  auto c = get_conn (handle);
  if (!c)
    cout << "Unable to open connection\n";

  return 0;
};
```

How can I replace `auto` keyword with actual return type of `std::unique_ptr` to compatible code with `c++11` ?

I tried with below return type but failed

```
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int *,int)> get_conn(int handle)
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Write an actual named class for your deleter, so you don't need to play `decltype` games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back to the functor!

The `auto` return type for functions is [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) feature. In order to provide the actual return type, you can provide a functor like follows(as *@IgorTandetnik* mentioned in the comments). The advantage is, that you do not need to `std::bind` any more.

### ([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qkr7stquFYwEVW3M))

```
struct DeleteConn  // functor which subsituts the lambda and `std::bind`
{
    int _handle;
    explicit DeleteConn(int handle): _handle{ handle } {}
    void operator()(int* conn) const
    {
        // API call                                                                                                                          
        close_conn(_handle, conn);
        delete conn;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<int, DeleteConn> get_conn(int handle)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---> now you can provide the actual type.
{
    // API call                                                                                                                                
    int* conn = open_conn(handle);
    DeleteConn delete_conn{ handle };
    return std::unique_ptr<int, DeleteConn>(conn, delete_conn);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can move the lambda function `delete_conn` out from the `get_conn` function and use the *[trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)* which is a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) fetaure.

### ([See Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HIIMSHneeYRAv1Bt))

```
namespace inter {
    auto delete_conn = [](int* conn, int handle)
    {
        // API call                                                                                                                          
        close_conn(handle, conn);
        delete conn;
    };
}

auto get_conn(int handle) 
->std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(std::bind(inter::delete_conn, std::placeholders::_1, handle))>
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --->Trailing return type
{
        // API call                                                                                                                                
        int* conn = open_conn(handle);
        auto delete_binded = std::bind(inter::delete_conn, std::placeholders::_1, handle);
        return std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(delete_binded)>(conn, delete_binded);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda is passed into `std::bind`, so you get another unnamed object, about which you know only it has `void (int*)` signature.

`int` as second param was bound, so it is mistake to put it in signature like `void(*)(int *,int)`. This functor takes only pointer to int.

Use `std::function`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>
get_conn (int handle)
{
  // API call                                                                                                                                
  int* conn = open_conn (handle);

  auto delete_conn = [](int *conn, int handle)
      {
        // API call                                                                                                                          
    close_conn (handle, conn);
    delete conn;
      };
  auto delete_binded = std::bind (delete_conn, std::placeholders::_1, handle);
  return std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)> > (conn, delete_binded);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YSit0x)